# LXDE Interactive password change

Tags: login, password

I wanted to know if its possible that LXDE ask for a new password at login time when the password has expired.  I can see that it works at console login it ask me for a password change, however, on graphic mode (LXDE) it just returns to login screen after entered my user and password and never asks me for a password chage.

Let me know if its possible to do so. I am ussing Lubuntu.

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems that this isn't possible with LXDM (yet - a feature request has been submitted so it may be possible in the future).

The workaround I employed was to install GDM as the login manager, which does accept responses from PAM (e.g. prompt for a new password when the current one has expired).

You can install GDM by type the following at a command prompt (LXTerminal):

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

This should give you a blue config screen. If you get any errors you may first need to run `sudo apt-get update`

You will then be prompted to choose your default display manager - select GDM. If you change your mind you can always go back and update this settings by typing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Reboot, and GDM will now be your display manager.

By default GDM gives a list of all the users on the system. I preferred to just have a text box rather than a list, which can be achieved with the command

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list 'true'
```

which just gives a 'Log In' button, and then a username box (similar to LXDM).

Hope this helps,

Gav

Comment: Wonderful first answer on askubuntu, Axiant. Welcome!